# UPDATE nvarchar results in Infinity or other unsuspected value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, infinity

While running simple update query on a table where all updated fields are nvarchar(50) I noticed strange behavior. From time to time (what is the first strange thing) instead of getting values properly updated, I get something what looks like a result of some calculation. When I run the same query again it results are like I expect them to be there.
Anyone seen it before and know any solution for this?
Please see example:

```
Query:
UPDATE Tabl1 
SET [D1] = '43 / 57.43 %', [D2] = '20 / 41.18 %', [D3] = '145 / 27.50 %', 
    [D4] = '59 / 28.92 %', [D5] = '143 / 36.44 %', [D6] = '14 / 53.33 %', 
    [D7] = '0 / 0.00 %', [D8] = '424 / 37.00 %',[D9] = '0 / 0.00 %' 
WHERE [key] = 28

Result:
D1 = 100
D2 = 100
D3 = 100
D4 = Infinity
D5 = 41.67
D6 = 100
D7 = 100
D8 = Infinity
D9 = Infinity
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Show us some real code. The query/result you've shown us at the moment clearly aren't related, since the result of the query should be something like `1 row updated`, and no result set.

Comment: You are assigning string values. It shouldn't be evaluated as an expression. If the column was numeric, you'd get an error. Also, I assume SQL Server because of [ ].

Comment: Damiel_The_Unbelieber - The first part is a real query I use. A result like you asked is "(1 row(s) affected)". I showed the exact result in DB after running query above.

gbn - I agree, that it shoul not evaluate it as an expression. The column is nvarchar(50) and I am passing exacly a string. And correct asumption, this is SQL Server 2008 if it makes any difference.

Comment: Is someone/something else also working on this database? Perhaps your values are just being overwritten.

Comment: If you wrap your `update` and `select` in a transaction, does this ever happen?

Comment: _Martin Smith_ - This is what I thought. The query is submitted to the DB by the VB application using `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`. There is a triger on this table used to do somee calculation, but it does not affect this fields, and definitely does not change query. The query I posted above is exacly the one from the SqlCommand.

_Blorgbeard_ - there are some people working on it, but this issue afects only a part of the table where I update data with the query above.

Comment: @user1158015 - Can you post the trigger code? Also any concurrent users?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't coming from SQL Server.

SQL Server has no such logic to evaluate calculations and return strings like "Infinity".

You must have triggers on the table that performs this rewrite or whatever you are using to submit the query rewrites it.

Comment: _Martin_, query I mentioned above is the same one passed to the SqlCommand and execute with funciton Executenonquery. I doublechecked if anything can change it in the meantime, but it has to be executed this way. Maybe I should rephrase the questions and ask if VB SqlCommand class may do something like this. On the DB end I checked what the trigger is doing and it takes the [key] and run another stored procedure with this key as parameter. SP is used to recalculate the values in table, and the update to this table is done i 5 places, and none of them can affecting values that I try to update.

Comment: @Lucas_Kul - No. VB SQL Command doesn't capriciously change your update queries either. It must be something specific to either code or other users your end.